# Python creating a custom day view excel

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

With the code above, I'm currently trying to achieve the following result:

```
  Day:          1   |   2   |   3   |   4  ...etc
____________________________________________________
    Google      00:00   09:22  00:00    00:00
    Stack       01:00   00:00  03:00    00:00


line_ = 6
col_ = 2

for i in range(1, 32): # From Day 1 to Day 31
    cr.execute("SELECT enti.entity, servic.hour_begin " \
      "FROM services AS servic " \
      "JOIN alljobs AS jobs ON jobs.id = servic.job_id " \
      "JOIN entities AS enti ON enti.id = jobs.entity_id" \
      "WHERE servic.create_uid = %s AND " \
      "EXTRACT(MONTH FROM servic.date_registered) = %s AND " \
      "EXTRACT(DAY FROM servic.date_registered) = %s",[5, 9, i])
      # The values: 5 and 9, will be different..is just for testing
    value = cr.fetchall()

    if value:
       for values in value:
           #sheet.write(line_, 0, values[0], style_main)
           sheet.write(line_, col_, values[1], style_main)  
           col_ += 1
    else:
       sheet.write(line_, col_, '00:00', style_main)
       col_ += 1

    if i == 31: 
       col_ = 2
       line_ += 1
```

Although, the code reproduces the following table:

```
 Day:          1   |   2   |   3   |   4  ...etc
             01:00   09:22  03:00    00:00
```

The query can show many results, because many services can be made in one day, that's why I did the second loop. Thanks.

Comment: I dont see a question here?

Comment: Well, the question was how to reproduce the last example in the final of the post. Although, I came to the conclusion that is not what I really want, and I found the resolution for what I want I think. As soon as I get this straight, I put here the code.